# Problems printing OpenLayers Plugin Maps To Scale

Tags: qgis, openlayers-2, openstreetmap, print-composer, printing

In the print composer I can print all maps to scale and satisfactory.
However, when I add the OpenLayers, usually Bing Aerial, to the project I cannot print it out to scale. I click the scale box, set it to the relevant scale.

The image below is a section of the actual size with OS mapping:

[image]

The next image is with the OpenLayers.

[image]

Both images cropped to remove client info. It is almost double the size but in-between scales. Is there any way to correct this?

Using Windows 7, QGIS 1.8.0.

Comment: Hi, I have similar problem, Qgis 1.8.0 and 1.9.0 nightly build, openlayer plugin 1.1.0, snow leopard 1.6.8. I filed a bug [here](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/7716). If this applies to you, let developers know I'm not alone!

Answer (score 0):

An incomplete and partial answer I'm afraid - but it may point you in a helpful direction:

I've had multiple problems trying to print with a background based on the Openlayers plugin.  The solution for me was to find a service which allowed me to download glued-together and georeferenced tiles from the web mapping I needed. For me this service is '[Bigmap](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Bigmap)' because it was Openstreetmap I wanted to use. I'm guessing that this is only one service/process of many which would achieve the same thing (but sorry I can't give any details).