# QGIS: when using composer to save as image the image has a shift of about 50m

Tags: qgis, openlayers-2

I'm using QGIS 1.8.0; I have two layers turned on, one is the Google Earth hybrid layer from the OpenLayers plugin and the other a shapefile of my own making.

I set on the fly projection and everything looks spot on in the active window. When I got to composer everything still looks good. It's only once I have saved the image (exported) that there is an issue.

I think I read about this earlier but I can't find the answer to it anywhere. I can't remember if it has to do with on the fly projection or not... it seems ridiculous that the composer doesn't just "print the screen" of what's displayed there.

Any help would be great.

Shapefile is located [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75077007/p5201239_tenement.zip)

On the fly projection is UTM 50S or EPSG:32750

Comment: Hi.  I have a similar question to this running in http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58401/problems-printing-openlayers-pluggin-maps-to-scale

Comment: I think it is something to do with the CRS for the globe not readily translating onto a 2d plain for printing to scale. The globe is round and hense lines are curved whereas standard printing to scale only allows for printing in straight lines.  correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I can not reproduce your error.

If you are working with the openlayers plugin, **project** CRS **must** be EPSG:3857, and nothing else.

With that, the shapefile stays at the same spot even in print composer. Unless you are zooming in very close, but that is another bug of the plugin.
[image]

Comment: Cheers Andre! though this fixes the issue per se, what i was after was a composer with my local gridlines (epsg 32750) on the image, not 3857... though it does fix the issue when i export and image through composer, it doesnt help me with my gridlines!

Comment: You can create a vector grid layer in any CRS, and display it over the Google imagery in EPSG:3857. But that would be another question.

Comment: Maybe this question can help you with UTM grids: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28870/add-utm-labels-to-grid-in-qgis

Answer (score 1):

On-the-fly projection is used for display and query purposes only. The actual data is not altered. Source: http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?id=2594&pid=2583&topicname=About_projecting_raster_datasets_on_the_fly

That means the assigned projection is not embedded in the shape file. Therefore, when you export the shape file and then display it somehow, somewhere else you are exporting it without the projection information.

I would use the normal projection tools, instead of on-the-fly projection.